# Facilities all showing as Unlocated in ArcGIS Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, network-analyst, service-area

I have a list of facilities that I have imported based off their addresses.  I matched all the points in the Esri geocoder based off USA street address locators.  These points are all accurate, and contain location data as well as street name, city, state, zip, etc.

I am using a network dataset that was included with Esri Streetmap Premium V10.2, called Routing_ND.  When I run my facility points through other network datasets, such as the Esri Tutorial San Fransisco Data, I do not receive any errors and it runs just fine.

The problem I am having is that when I create a service layer based off "Routing_ND" and add these locations to my Facilities class, the points all show up as "Unlocated" and I am unable to change/have them located in order to run on my "Make Service Area Layer".

The "Routing_ND" also appears to not show any edges or traffic data even when checked on in the symbology tab.  This is one of the only differences I am able to find when comparing to other network datasets.

I have my Network Analyst extension checked off in both my ArcMap session as well as ArcCatalog, and I have the active license installed for SMP (.sdlic file).

Any ideas?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101530/discussion-on-question-by-spencer-facilities-all-showing-as-unlocated-in-arcgis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to a license issue (may have purchased Map Display + Geocoding instead of a license that includes Routing). There are different price points and access restrictions for each of the license levels available for purchase from Esri. Check with your license administrator or Esri sales representative.

Also note: the download/unzipping process can be tricky; make sure all of the zip files are downloaded to same location before unzipping, and unzip each of the first file for each group (e.g. locators, fgdb). The process should trigger the unzipping of similarly named files. An unzipping problem doesn't appear to be the issue based on responses in chat.